# c# Linq differed execution challenge - help needed in creating 3 different lists

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to create 3 different lists (1,2,3) from 2 existing lists (A,B).
The 3 lists need to identify the following relationships.

- List 1 - the items that are in list A and not in list B
- List 2 - the items that are in list B and not in list A
- List 3 - the items that are in both lists.

I then want to join all the lists together into one list.

My problem is that I want to identify the differences by adding an enum identifying the relationship to the items of each list. But by adding the Enum the `Except` Linq function does not identify the fact (obviously) that the lists are the same. Because the Linq queries are differed I can not resolve this by changing the order of my statements ie. identify the the lists and then add the Enums.

This is the code that I have got to (Doesn't work properly)
There might be a better approach.

```
        List<ManufactorListItem> manufactorItemList =
           manufactorRepository.GetManufactorList();

        // Get the Manufactors from the Families repository
        List<ManufactorListItem> familyManufactorList =
            this.familyRepository.GetManufactorList(familyGuid);

        // Identify Manufactors that are only found in the Manufactor Repository
        List<ManufactorListItem> inManufactorsOnly =
            manufactorItemList.Except(familyManufactorList).ToList();

        // Mark them as (Parent Only)
        foreach (ManufactorListItem manOnly in inManufactorsOnly) {
            manOnly.InheritanceState = EnumInheritanceState.InParent;
        }

        // Identify Manufactors that are only found in the Family Repository
        List<ManufactorListItem> inFamiliesOnly =
            familyManufactorList.Except(manufactorItemList).ToList();

        // Mark them as (Child Only)
        foreach (ManufactorListItem famOnly in inFamiliesOnly) {
            famOnly.InheritanceState = EnumInheritanceState.InChild;
        }

        // Identify Manufactors that are found in both Repositories
        List<ManufactorListItem> sameList =
            manufactorItemList.Intersect(familyManufactorList).ToList();

        // Mark them Accordingly
        foreach (ManufactorListItem same in sameList) {
            same.InheritanceState = EnumInheritanceState.InBoth;
        }

        // Create an output List
        List<ManufactorListItem> manufactors = new List<ManufactorListItem>();

        // Join all of the lists together.
        manufactors = sameList.Union(inManufactorsOnly).
            Union(inFamiliesOnly).ToList();
```

Any ideas hot to get around this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it much simplier:

```
List<ManufactorListItem> manufactorItemList = ...;
List<ManufactorListItem> familyManufactorList = ...;
var allItems = manufactorItemList.ToDictionary(i => i, i => InheritanceState.InParent);

foreach (var familyManufactor in familyManufactorList)
{
    allItems[familyManufactor] = allItems.ContainsKey(familyManufactor) ?
                                 InheritanceState.InBoth : 
                                 InheritanceState.InChild;
}

//that's all, now we can get any subset items:  

var inFamiliesOnly = allItems.Where(p => p.Value == InheritanceState.InChild).Select(p => p.Key);
var inManufactorsOnly = allItems.Where(p => p.Value == InheritanceState.InParent).Select(p => p.Key);
var allManufactors = allItems.Keys;
```

Comment: @Snowbear - Thanks ever so much. You have really helped me ;0). I still need to build the list with the enum in it, but that seems a simple task now.

Comment: @Snowbear - I have implemented your solution but still seem to have one slight issue I thought you might be able to add some insight on. The InBoth case does not get caught. For some reason even though both structures (familyManufactor and manufactorItem) are exactly the same. Do I need to add a comparer like Stuart recommended?

Comment: @Julian, Yes, `manufactors` should implement correct `Equals` behavior. I though you implemented it, because your initial `Excepts` also require this.

Comment: @Julian, Stuart seems to propose a little bit different solution. I mean you should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `ManufactorListItem` class

Comment: @Snowbear thanks, Where should I add this to the dictionary code above The ContainsKey function does not take a comparer.

Comment: I think the Equals behaviour is the root to all the problems - it's why the original pseudocode didn't work. The two lists contain elements which you consider equal, but which are actually separate objects. To get around this, you either need to use IEqualityComparer<> in Except or you need to use @Snowbear's modified code and you need to override Equals and GetHashCode inside your ManufactorListItem implementation. Hope that makes sense - sorry it's harder to add formatting in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with the Except() statement, then I suggest you use the 3 parameter override of Except in order to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<ManufactorListItem> compare` which tests the appropriate ManufactorListItem fields, but not the InheritanceState.

e.g. your equality comparer might look like:

```
public class ManufactorComparer : IEqualityComparer<ManufactorListItem>  { 
  public bool Equals(ManufactorListItem x, ManufactorListItem y)  { 
    // you need to write a method here that tests all the fields except InheritanceState 
  }  
  public int GetHashCode(ManufactorListItem obj)  { 
    // you need to write a simple hash code generator here using any/all the fields except InheritanceState
  } 
}
```

and then you would call this using code a bit like

```
// Identify Manufactors that are only found in the Manufactor Repository
List<ManufactorListItem> inManufactorsOnly =
        manufactorItemList.Except(familyManufactorList, new ManufactorComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still trying to get the grip on your proposal.

Comment: As far as I can see the problem you have is that currently your Except is working on the equals level of "is a reference to the same object". Instead of that you need to work on comparing fields to do this - if you do that, then your original pseudo-code should work. Hang on - I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think I should create a new question and accept your answer there, As both your and Snowbears answers are correct. I guess my lack of knowledge caused this, so if its OK with you I'll add a question and we can add a link to it from here. In order to help other SO users while searching I think the title should be: C# Linq how do I compare two objects that have the same values but are two different instances.

Comment: Relax - no worries about adding artificial questions - SO has enough questions already. Thanks for the thanks - you can always say thanks by upvoting my answers and my apps too :) Good luck with fixing the code!

Comment: Accepted - I learn something new every day, I was also a bit unhappy with my offer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the simplest way to me:

(I'm using the following Enum for simplicity:

```
public enum ContainedIn
{
    AOnly,
    BOnly,
    Both
}
```

)

```
var la = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
var lb = new List<int> {2, 3, 4};

var l1 = la.Except(lb)
           .Select(i => new Tuple<int, ContainedIn>(i, ContainedIn.AOnly));
var l2 = lb.Except(la)
           .Select(i => new Tuple<int, ContainedIn>(i, ContainedIn.BOnly));
var l3 = la.Intersect(lb)
           .Select(i => new Tuple<int, ContainedIn>(i, ContainedIn.Both));

var combined = l1.Union(l2).Union(l3);
```

So long as you have access to the `Tuple<T1, T2>` class (I think it's a .NET 4 addition).

Comment: I have just approved Snowbears answer (Before I read yours) I am working with 3.5 so I guess Tuple is not an option.

Comment: In Tuple's defence, it is an easy class to write, but Snowbear's solution is good.